Hreflang on noindex urls: keep or delete?
i am dealing with aproximative 6000 noindex urls that have the hreflang setup also on the noindex urls. My plan is to delete all hreflangs from the noindex urls and leave them without any hreflang reference.
What am I risking here? Shall i go ahead?
Many thanks in advance!
